# Selenium Builder 3 CSS Selector Substring Match

Tags: selenium, selenium-builder

Currently i'm learning how to use Selenium Builder 3 and how to use all of its tools; however, I ran into an issue along the lines of grabbing the correct ID of an element.

The website i'm writing a test for auto-generates ID's and every time you navigate to the page it changes those ID's. I know XPath will solve the problem but i'd like to make the test dynamic. I did find out the CSS Selector ID for the particular element does contain the same number of 'x' characters at the end of the string, but I don't know how to provide css=a[id$='_id_sufix'] to Selenium and cannot find any documentation/tutorials.

Here's more information to better explain my issue.

[This is where the test hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb8FK.png)

[This is where I enter in the ID name or CSS Selector (both fail for me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZZEd.png)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [CSS3 [attribute*=value] Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp).

For example, for `<div id='test123'>`, the following CSS selector will match:

```
div[id*="test"]
```

This will match a `<div>` with an `id` containing the string `"test"`.

Comment: See that's what i'm saying, it's not working in Selenium Builder where you input the locator.

Comment: looks like you have a `$` instead of a `*`

Comment: so that means `'input[id*=6_1_1-inputEl]'` and `'input[id$=6_1_1-inputEl]'` , as well as, `input[id*='6_1_1-inputEl'` and `input[id$='6_1_1-inputEl'` aren't working for me in Selenium Builder.

Comment: from your screenshot, it looks like you selected `id` instead of `css selector`

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was the syntax. Thanks for helping me, I really appreciate it! By the way whoever is reading this, the final result is - `css selector: input[id*="yoursubstring"]`